# how to add project manager to TFS 2012

Tags: permissions, team-foundation-server

I have upgraded to TFS 2012 and I have trying to make full use of the Web Access feature for Scrum project management but have come accross a problem with permissions:

I have added Developers to the Default team that is set up when I create the Team project, this is fine as it gives everyone access to the Website and Check out/in source control.

I now want to add a project manager to the Web Access site with permissions to use only the portal, but I can not find any obvious way of doing this:

If I add them as a team member they will get rights to edit/view the source.
If I add them as a reader this will prevent them changes any of the source and allow them on the site but they can not do anything like assign backlog items, create bugs or do test runs.

Does anyone know a way of setting upa user that only has permissions to carry out tasks on the Web Access only with no permissions to Source Control?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a new TFS permissions group via the "Group Membership" dialog under either "Team Project Collections" or "Application Tier" in the Administration Console, for a collection-specific or server-wide group, respectively.

With or without a dedicated group, to deny all source control access, open up Source Control Explorer in VS, right click the root folder, then select "Advanced > Security...". Click Add and select either the group you created above or the individual user if you did not create a group. You should then be able to simply deny whichever permissions you want, here.

To explicitly grant permissions for Web Access for a given project, go to the web access administration panel, select the project to which you wish to grant access, then select "Manage project security and group membership". Select the "areas" tab, then right click the root area and select "Security" from the context menu. Click Add and select the group or individual, as before, then set the appropriate permissions on the right.

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: I have created a group within the application tier and if I turn off "View instave-level information" this solves it, but the then can not have access to the Website. I have tried doing the security permission on the Collection but this is overwritten when you add them in the Team

Comment: If members of the group can access both work items and source control, follow the instructions in my second paragraph to deny source control access. Otherwise, could you clarify what group members can and cannot access?

Comment: I have followed the 2nd paragraph with no joy. The problem is, everyone can access web access and source control. I want ever user I had to access both with the exception of users that are in a "Project Managers" TFS group. Users in the Project Managers group should only have access to the Web Access functionality